# How to make coloured text in Jupyter Notebook work in Github?

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook

When I upload a Jupyter Notebook into Github, the markdown html for coloured text doesn't work, it just shows up as

```
 <font color=#C8CAC6> table of contents </font>
```

If colours cannot work in Github, is there an alternate to Github where I can upload my Jupyter Notebooks with coloured text? Also, is there a fast way to remove all the HTML code, so it doesn't appear on Github?

Comment: Have you tried viewing the notebook via [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/)? It generally renders more features than Github’s rendering of the static notebook. You just need to paste the Github URL ( or gist URL) for the notebook into the form on the nbviewer page to render the notebook.